# Question of subplot in matlab irregularity

Tags: matlab

How can I draw the plot as follow in matlab?
using subpolt?
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you plotting here?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using subplot with the 'Position' argument.

```
subplot('Position',[x,y,width,height])
```

In your example

```
% third row
subplot('Position',[0,0,.25,.33]);
sphere
subplot('Position',[.25,0,.25,.33]);
sphere
subplot('Position',[.5,0,.25,.33]);
sphere
subplot('Position',[.75,0,.25,.33]);
sphere

% second row
subplot('Position',[.125,.33,.25,.33]);
sphere
subplot('Position',[.375,.33,.25,.33]);
sphere
subplot('Position',[.625,.33,.25,.33]);
sphere

% first row
subplot('Position',[.25,.66,.25,.33]);
sphere
subplot('Position',[.5,.66,.25,.33]);
sphere
```

will lead to something like 
[image: this]

I guess you will have to adjust the actual position values a bit depending on your plots and how you handle axis labels and everything...